# How to get Xcode debugger to show 'self' and variable values again?

Tags: ios, swift, debugging

For some reason, Xcode has stopped showing the value of 'self' when debugging (it just says 'self' and nothing else. Local variables are showing, though. Also if I add *valid* values with Add Expression, they always say Invalid Expression.

It used to work well until a while ago, although I can't determine when it last worked. The debugger seems to work well for other projects, so I'm guessing it's something in the project settings.

I've inspected build settings, and made sure that optimization values are set to None [-Oo] for debug (and None [-Onone] in Swift).

I've also made sure that the current scheme is Debug, and that Debug Scheme has 'Debug executable' selected.

This is a Swift project, with some Objective-C files, and it's in Xcode 6.4 (6E35b).

How can I get Xcode to show the value of 'self' again, and to display values of expressions that I add in the debugger?

Comment: I have the same issue! Let me know if you figure out how to solve it!

Comment: I'm still struggling with this... I figure that there must be something in the project settings that I changed accidentally, because if I revert way back to an older version of the code, the debugger works normally. Unfortunately, it's so far back that even using those settings isn't an option.

Comment: For my situation, I think it had to do something with crashlytics. Do you happen to have that installed?

Comment: @AustinT I do!! Do you happen to remember what you did?

Comment: @AustinT you were right! I just uninstalled Crashlytics to see what would happen, and the variables are back! I'll post a full answer when I figure out the correct installation.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved this.

@AustinT and anyone who runs into this:

The problem for me was caused by a double installation of crashlytics, through cocoapods and through traditional installation. 
I tried to leave only the cocoapods version for hours, following the official guide, but I couldn't get it to work. I got a 'not found' message on the build phase script.

So eventually I gave up and just left the traditional installation version, and erased every mention of the pod version in the project.

The debugger went back to normal, and life is good again.